# Query with values prepended by ampersand - works in Oracle but not in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

In MySQL, the statement below works:

```
mysql>insert into emp1(empno,empname,empsal,empcity) values (100,'vinay',10000,'USA');**

mysql> select * from emp1;
+-------+---------+--------+---------+
| empno | empname | empsal | empcity |
+-------+---------+--------+---------+
|   100 | vinay   |  10000 | USA     |
+-------+---------+--------+---------+
```

In Oracle, the statement below works:

```
mysql> insert into emp1 values(&empno,'&empname',&empsal,'&empcity');**
```

But this doesn't work in MySQL - why can't the values be prepended by `&`?

Comment: k can you tell me how to write those tables in a proper line format .do we have anything to add before writing the table.

Comment: Can't you wrap values with quotes? like '&empno'

Comment: Because PL_sql is not the same language as MYSQLs SQL implementation. The use of variables is vendor specific. You are asking why doesn't my C# code work in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar code for MySQL is like this:

```
SET @empno = 100, @empname = 'vinay', @empsal = 10000, @empcity = 'USA'; 
insert into emp1 values(@empno,@empname,@empsal,@empcity);
```

Note the `@`, no `'` in the `INSERT` values, etc.

If you are translating between different DBMS systems, you should plan on significant rewriting.  This is just one of hundreds of differences between Oracle and MySQL.

Answer (score 6):

Am assuming the ampersands are for [SQL*Plus substitution variables](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/sqlplus_101_substitution_varia#2_2).

These are supported by Oracle but not by MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

'&' is supported in Oracle but not in MySQL that's why It gives compilation error in MySQL.